# Derivatives are not matching textbook. Are my assumptions or calculations wrong?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am trying to follow a derivation in a book, but I get a different result and can't figure out what I'm missing.

I have a system of equations like this:

\begin{align}
\dot{r} &= v \\
0 &= g(r) \\
\end{align}
Now the book specifies that all variables are functions of t. So I guess that means $r(t)$, and $v(r(t))$ and $g(r(t))$.

The book then calculates $\dot{g}$:
\begin{align}
\dot{g} &= \frac{\partial g}{\partial r} \frac{\partial r}{\partial t} \\ 
&= G v
\end{align}
with $G=\frac{\partial g}{\partial r}$.
So far so good.
But next it calculates $\ddot{g}$:
\begin{align}
\ddot{g} &= \frac{\partial (G v)}{\partial t} \\ 
&= \frac{\partial G }{\partial t} v + G \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} \\
&= \frac{\partial G}{\partial r} \frac{\partial r}{\partial t} v + G \frac{\partial v}{\partial r} \frac{\partial r}{\partial t} \\ 
&= \frac{\partial G}{\partial r} v^2 + G \frac{\partial v}{\partial r} v 
\end{align}
However the book gets:
\begin{equation}
\ddot{g} = G \dot{v} + \frac{\partial (Gv)}{\partial r} v
\end{equation}
which if I expand it out is not the same. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely made a wrong assumption. On the other hand, the answer given by the book is kinda weird, unless there's a specific reason for writing it that way.

The only explicit function composition stated by the problem is $(g \circ r)(t)$, but you assumed, perhaps influenced by the uncommon form of the given answer, that $v$ was also a function composition $(v \circ r)(t)$. Considering $v$ as a function of $t$ only, we get
$$
\ddot{g} = {\partial(Gv) \over \partial t} = {\partial G \over \partial t}v+ G{\partial v \over \partial t} = {\partial G \over \partial r}{\partial r \over \partial t}v + G\dot{v} = {\partial G \over \partial r}v^2 + G\dot{v}.
$$
If $v$ is independent of $r$, it acts as a constant under differentiation w.r.t $r$, so
$$
{\partial G \over \partial r}v^2 = {\partial (Gv) \over \partial r}v.
$$
That's a very... *particular* way of writing it and, unless it's useful for some manipulation later on, I don't see why the author choose to express it like that.

Comment: That was actually the first calculation I did as well, I just never saw the last connection. I think the author keeps it like this for numerical reasons later on, but yeah it definitely threw me off.
Thank you!